# datatables : If I decide to use lazy loading would search show incorrect data?

Tags: datatables

I have a large amount of text information which I'll be loading in a table.
I want the user to search through it, using datatables search.

I wasn't doing **lazy loading** earlier, but now I'm **thinking of using it now**.
However, if I lazy load and the user **searches for data**, he/she won't be able to see everything, since the data isn't completely loaded.

Am I guess this correctly or does datatables work around this somehow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two processing modes: client-side and server-side, see [Processing modes](http://datatables.net/manual/data#Processing-modes) for more information.

- Client-side processing - the full data set is loaded up-front and searching/filtering/pagination is done in the browser.
- Server-side processing - an Ajax request is made for every table redraw, with only the data required for each display returned. Searching/filtering/pagination is performed on the server.

There is also [Scroller](http://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/) extension, it's a virtual rendering plug-in for DataTables which allows large datasets to be drawn on screen very quickly.

Along with server-side processing it could be used to perform lazy loading of large amount of data. When searching, the request will be made to the server to search the whole dataset and only subset needed to be displayed at the moment will be returned.

See [Server-side processing](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side) for more information on request and response in server-side processing mode.